# CMake not adding full RPATH on macOS

Tags: c++, cmake, rpath

I have the following MWE where Conan is used to install the `fmt` library (shared).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(Test CXX)

set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
  message(STATUS "Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
  file(DOWNLOAD "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/v0.16.1/conan.cmake"
                "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake"
                EXPECTED_HASH SHA256=396e16d0f5eabdc6a14afddbcfff62a54a7ee75c6da23f32f7a31bc85db23484
                TLS_VERIFY ON)
endif()

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake)

conan_cmake_configure(REQUIRES fmt/6.1.2
                      OPTIONS fmt:shared=True
                      GENERATORS cmake_find_package)

conan_cmake_autodetect(settings)

conan_cmake_install(PATH_OR_REFERENCE .
                    BUILD missing
                    REMOTE conancenter
                    SETTINGS ${settings})

find_package(fmt)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main fmt::fmt)
```

When I inspect the executable `otool -l main` I see that
the `fmt` library has no absolute path, which I expect to happen. **So also the executbale can not be run, because it doesn find `libfmtd.6.dylib`.**

The question is, what is wrongly setup here and why is there no full path encoded in the executable?

**Output `otool` :**

```sh
Load command 13
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 40
         name libfmtd.6.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 01:00:02 1970
      current version 6.1.2
compatibility version 6.0.0
Load command 14
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 01:00:02 1970
      current version 1200.3.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 15
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 01:00:02 1970
      current version 1311.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
```

The link command has been:

```sh
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.21.4/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/main.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -g 
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk 
-mmacosx-version-min=11.4 -Wl,-search_paths_first 
-Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names 
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o 
-o main  
/Users/.../.conan/data/fmt/6.1.2/_/_/package/8cb4659713397fdd78e4947cac0468f7f7ca515d/lib/libfmtd.dylib
```

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan#keep_rpaths is what you need. I don't have experience with conan, but looking on the path to package it seems they have reasons to remove conan-based paths.

Comment: But I am questioning, which Cmake code produces this behavior. I dont see anything suspicious in the Findfmt.cmake script generated from Conan. ?

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky: `KEEP_RPATHS`  is not used in this approach by Conan.cmake and has no effect.

Comment: It's somewhere inside `conan.cmake` script you are downloading. Wasn't able to quickly trace it, but this page describes behaviour: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/manage_shared_libraries/rpaths.html?highlight=keep_rpath

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky No its not there, its not respected, and has no impact.
Only CMake is involved once conan install has been run.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies probably in the fact how conan builds `fmt` during `conan_cmake_install`
It builds it without RPATHs meaning, the resulting `fmt` library contains
a `LC_ID_DYLIB` section:

`otool -L /Users/.../.conan/data/fmt/8.0.1/_/_/package/09858fb580f8c1d91b81bfdbedd881822cc5da84/lib/libfmtd.dylib` gives:

```
Load command 4
          cmd LC_ID_DYLIB
      cmdsize 40
         name libfmtd.8.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 1 Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970
      current version 8.0.1
compatibility version 8.0.0
```

And this path `name libfmtd.8.dylib ...` gets embedded in the executable `main`.

The library fmt should have been built with RPATH enabled resulting in a

```
Load command 4
          cmd LC_ID_DYLIB
      cmdsize 40
         name @rpath/libfmtd.8.dylib (offset 24)
```

together with an additional RPATH in the executable `main` which will point to"

```
/Users/.../.conan/data/fmt/8.0.1/_/_/package/09858fb580f8c1d91b81bfdbedd881822cc5da84/lib/
```

which will be added by cmake automatically (IMO?).